# call server to execute method from client

Tags: mongodb, meteor, twitter-streaming-api

I'm playing working on a twitter streaming app using meteorjs. However, I have a problem destroying the stream and replace with a new one when the user enter a new track keyword. How am I able to call twitter streaming to destroy and stream new track on the server side when there a user enter a new track keyword?

//in client.js

```
Template.executefb.events({
'keyup input#searchFeedback': 
  function(e) { 
    if(e.which == '13')
    {
      var tag = $('#searchFeedback').val();
      var exist = searchTag(tag, 'feedback');
      if(typeof exist == 'undefined')
      {
        Meteor.call('addNewTag',tag, 'feedback');

       //I want to call server to call Meteor.call('getLatestTag', 'feedback');
       // and Meteor.call('streamTwit', Fiber, twit, feedback); in server again


      }
     Meteor.call('clearSearchbar');
    }
  }
});
```

//in server.js

```
var require;
var ntwitter;
var Fiber;


require = Npm.require;
ntwitter = require('ntwitter');
Fiber = require('fibers');


var twit = new ntwitter({
consumer_key: 'some key',
consumer_secret: 'some key',
access_token_key: 'some key',
access_token_secret: 'some key'
});

//get latest tag entered by the user from mongodb
var feedback = Meteor.call('getLatestTag', 'feedback');

//this method call starts twitter streaming
Meteor.call('streamTwit', Fiber, twit, feedback);
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this to your `server.js`

```
Meteor.methods({
    changeStream: function() {
        //get latest tag entered by the user from mongodb
        var feedback = Meteor.call('getLatestTag', 'feedback');

        //this method call starts twitter streaming
        Meteor.call('streamTwit', Fiber, twit, feedback);
    }
});
```

And in your client:

```
if(typeof exist === 'undefined') {
    Meteor.call('addNewTag', tag, 'feedback', function() {
        Meteor.call("changeStream");
    });
}
```

**NOTE:** you could simply pass the `tag` up to the `changeStream` method instead of waiting for the callback on the `addNewTag` method, then forgo the server-side `getLatestTag` because you'd already have it.